# Mechanize: Only following links with certain element in URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, mechanize

Learning Mechanize:
I am wanting to crawl through a news site and only follow the links that have a `?sid` in the link.. 
I cannot seem to find much on Mechanize documentation.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("http://www.ksl.com")
target_url = 'http://www.ksl.com/?sid=23201788&nid=711&title=vampire-on-the-loose-in-serbia'

for link in br.links():
    print link.text, link.lurl
```

That's as far as I have now. I would like Mechanize to go to the main page of KSL, open each link, with that `?sid` in the URL, and then, within that url, search for the target URL. Then go back, and continue searching the different links on the page. At the end of the front page there is a "page number" at the bottom which goes back pretty far, so I would need it to turn to the 'next page' to scan more links.... So I want to see which stories have the target URL in it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> target_url = 'http://www.ksl.com/?sid=23201788&nid=711&title=vampire-on-the-loose-in-serbia'
>>> parsed_url = urlparse(target_url)
>>> parsed_url
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.ksl.com', path='/', params='', query='sid=23201788&nid=711&title=vampire-on-the-loose-in-serbia', fragment='')
>>> if 'sid=' in parsed_url.query:
...     do_something()
```